# How to search three or more arrays row by row for an optimum value in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, search, optimization

I  have a few variables and here they are, three variables *"R1, R2 and R3"* each have a size of  *[40 x 1]*.
I have a fourth variable U of the same dimension. For every  U(i) I need to search for an optimum value within R1(i), R2(i) and R3(i) which would return a single value solution. I intend to plot the optimum value against U9i).I have been trying to wrap my head around the knnsearch function but no luck.

Any one out there who could please help??

Thanks

Comment: What defines the "optimum value" for you? Is it "the value in one of R1, R2, R3 that is closest to the corresponding value in U?"

Comment: The optimum value is the highest of the three. Its actually

Comment: You never finished your comment… I am pretty sure you don't need knnsearch though. If you think you do, then you need to explain MUCH better what your problem is, what you have tried, etc…

Comment: Hi ,Thanks I used;>> for i=1:length(R); R(i) =   max([R1(i),R2(i) R3(i)]); end; %Any comments

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, this might be what you need:

```
RR = [R1(:) R2(:) R3(:)];
d = bsxfun(@minus,RR, U(:));
[m mi] = min(abs(d),[],2);
answer = RR(:,mi);
```

first - put the three vectors into a single matrix:

```
RR = [R1(:) R2(:) R3(:)];
```

next, take the difference with U: `bsxfun` is ideal for this kind of thing

```
d = bsxfun(@minus,RR, U(:));
```

Now find the minimum absolute difference for each row:

```
[m mi] = min(abs(d),[],2);
```

The corresponding indices should allow you to find the "best fit"

```
answer = RR(:,mi);
```

I had to do some mind reading to get to this 'answer', so feel free to correct my misunderstanding of your problem!

**update** if you just need the highest of the three values, then

```
val = max([R1(:) R2(:) R3(:)]');
plot(U, val);
```

should be all you need...

Comment: Thanks @Flora i've tried it out but justs prints out the first line of the three rows, guess I have something to crack on....

Comment: Is that with the first or the second method I posted? What are the values of `mi` that you get? Could it be because the first "solution" was solving the wrong problem? Anyway - if I gave you the impetus to tackle the problem in a different light, then I'm glad.

Answer (score 0):

Well when I can't wrap my head around something, I don't come here first.

- A lot of people forget this one because we are online, but read a book on the topic. Have your code open so when you see something in the book, test it out.
- Draw out any type of diagram. I call these *"Napkin Diagrams"*, because I write it on anything, even a napkin.
- I play with code until my keyboard has no letters left on it, then I keep plugging away until the keys fall off
- Explore the language  API's
- Check for public repositories that you can play with
- Google, is okay for a quick reference, but google will not teach you anything other than how to google
- I talk my code over with myself all the time, people think I'm nuts, but so do I . . It actually works sometimes.

Then if I still can't get it, I come here with a list of things that I have tried, sample code that has not worked, etc.

I used to hate when people told me this, but that was the best thing anyone could have done for me so I tend to do the same now" Thinking about coding is a big part, but u have to get done wht u can. Then we all know what level u are at. Plus it being the end of semester a lot of these types of questions are homework... 
Thinking is good, now turn those thoughts into a conceptual design . It's okay to be wrong in this stage, its all just conceptual